# How to resolve gnosis safe app template error?

Tags: gnosis-safe

[image]

I have created safe using Rinkeby then running my gnosis safe app react template after installing it and trying to run it not working.

Comment: Can you share which template you used? E.g. https://github.com/gnosis/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/cra-template-safe-app

Answer (score 0):

This looks like that you did not install the dependencies. Make sure to call `yarn install`.

If you use the official create react app template for Safe apps, then you just need to follow the steps in the [README](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/cra-template-safe-app/template).